# "UnknownHostException": Zookeeper 3.5.3 and StatefulSet Kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, statefulset

Zookeeper 3.5.3-beta does not work for me with GCloud Kubernetes Engine.  Using the identical configuration with Zookeeper 3.4.10 works.

When I run a client sanity test, the only exception returned is this:

```
2017-11-29 14:27:17,597 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181)(secure=disabled):Learner@273] - Unexpected exception, tries=0, remaining init limit=20000, connecting to zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:2888
java.net.UnknownHostException: zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

While it has been suggested that this problem is kube-dns related as indicated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2737.).
kube-dns (dns.go:48] version: 1.14.4-2-g5584e04) seems to be working as expected:

```
/ # nslookup zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.63.240.10
Address 1: 10.63.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.60.3.3 zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
/ # nslookup zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.63.240.10
Address 1: 10.63.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.60.4.3 zk-2.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
/ # nslookup zk-1.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.63.240.10
Address 1: 10.63.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      zk-1.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.60.2.5 zk-1.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

And there are no errors in the kube-dns log.

In 3.4.10, the first node also produces UnknownHostExceptions on initialization, but eventually provides this type of indication of resolution, but never in 3.5.3

```
2017-11-29 15:14:39,923 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@167] - Resolved hostname: zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local to address: zk-0.zk-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/10.60.4.4
```

I do not have enough information to file an issue with Zookeeper, so I would appreciate any suggestions on how to debug this.

Comment: I should add that the 3.5.3 configuration did require a change: I needed to also whitelist the 4 letter words with "4lw.commands.whitelist=*" in the configuration so that the readiness probe would work.  Also, "standaloneEnabled=false" was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a recent comment in [ZOOKEEPER-2343](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2343), I have deployed a 3.6.0-SNAPSHOT image.  The second and third nodes accept client requests immediately, but the first does not and reports "This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests".

Deleting the first node fixes that problem as when it starts, it can participate in the quorum.